# Minitab Histogram: Group bins as "larger than X"

Tags: excel, bar-chart, histogram, bins, minitab

As I am new to Minitab, I searched for quite a while in blogs, forums, youtube videos and even images first, but no luck.

I am looking for a possibility to group values in a histogram (i.e. bins?). I have a large data set that looks like this: [https://www.engr.mun.ca/~ggeorge/4421/demos/t1/i21barchart.png](https://www.engr.mun.ca/%7Eggeorge/4421/demos/t1/i21barchart.png) with a few outliers.

What I specifically want to do in this case is to add all the values above 15 in one single bar and label it as "15 and greater" (group all the outliers into a single bar). Excel does exactly this by default (see image): https://learnandteachstatistics.files.wordpress.com/2012/11/histogram_2.png

Any chance to do the same with Minitab?

Thanks in advance for the time and help.

---

### **edit: I found the answer via Minitab help and posted a screenshot below**

Answer (score 0):

Minitab histogram bins must be equally separated and distributed, all you can specify is a personalized set of bins, different of the automatically calculated ones, by clicking in bar chart area -> Edit Graph -> Edit Bars -> Binning -> Midpoint/Cutpoint positions; however, as I said, the bins must be equally distributed....